# Count total of entries in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables of data and want to display just the Location and the count of entries for that location. I'm struggling to create a sql statement to do this. I am using MS SQL server.

Below I used photoshop to show my three tables and how I am trying to get the final output to look:

[image]

Comment: you want to count rows of Entries that are tied to New York?  Id = 1? yes?

Comment: What have you tried ? Why you don't have a `dbo.Entries.EmployeeID` **FK** instead of `dbo.Entries.Name` ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I should probably use Employee ID rather than Name good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Employees TABLE (ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(100), BRANCH INT)
INSERT INTO @Employees
VALUES (1, 'jsmith', 4),(2, 'acook', 1),(3, 'jdoe', 4)

DECLARE @Branch TABLE (ID INT, NAME NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Branch
VALUES (1, 'New York'), (2,'California'),(3,'Illinos'),(4,'Maine')

DECLARE @Entries TABLE (ID INT, Employee VARCHAR(100), [Date] DateTime)
INSERT INTO @Entries
VALUES (1, 'jsmith', '2014-01-01 20:05:00.000'),(2, 'jsmith', '2014-01-03 20:05:00.000'),
(3, 'jdoe', '2014-01-04 20:05:00.000'),(4, 'jsmith', '2014-01-04 20:05:00.000'),
(5, 'jdoe', '2014-01-03 20:05:00.000'),(6, 'acook', '2014-01-02 20:05:00.000')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT B.NAME AS Location, ISNULL(Q.TotalEntries, 0) TotalEntries
FROM
(
SELECT B.NAME as Location, COUNT(*) TotalEntries
FROM @Entries EN INNER JOIN @Employees EM 
ON EM.name = EN.employee
INNER JOIN @Branch B 
ON EM.branch = B.id
GROUP BY b.name
) Q RIGHT JOIN @Branch B
ON Q.Location = B.NAME
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Location   ║ TotalEntries ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╣
║ New York   ║            1 ║
║ California ║            0 ║
║ Illinos    ║            0 ║
║ Maine      ║            5 ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT b.Name,count(n.employee)
FROM Branch b
LEFT JOIN Employee e ON e.branch=b.id
LEFT JOIN Entries n ON n.employee=e.name
GROUP BY b.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT B.Name AS [Location],
        COUNT(*)
 FROM Entries AS E
 JOIN Branch AS B
   ON B.Id = E.Id
 GROUP BY B.Name
 ORDER BY B.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

select b.branch, count(*) from branch b join employee e on e.branch = b.branch join entries s on s.employee = e.name group by b.branch

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.name 'location', isnull(count(e.branch), 0) as count_total 
from branch b 
left join employee e on e.branch = b.id
left join entries en on en.employee = e.name
group by b.name
```